# Angular form custom validator on two fields

Tags: javascript, angular, validation, formbuilder, formgroups

I have question how to valid on two fields simultaneously in Angular FormGroup.
I must create custom validation on value return backend
I don't have any idea how to create it.
Thanks for any idea.

Comment: You build a Validator for the FormGroup as opposed to for the FormControl. That allows you to check whether both fields are valid before validating the overall FormGroup.

Comment: You can use the same validator for each of them. From what your write, I can suggest you use [`AsyncValidator`](https://angular.io/api/forms/AsyncValidator)

Comment: I'll add that i must two value for at the same time, to check validation.

Answer (score 1):

You need to create AsyncValidator and bind it to the FormGroup, then you will have access to the group fields and can validate two fields in one validation tick. There is some example for you:

```
group = new FormGroup(
    {
      a: new FormControl(''),
      b: new FormControl(''),
    },
    { asyncValidators: customAsyncValidator() }
  );


function customAsyncValidator(): AsyncValidatorFn {
  return (group: FormGroup) => {
    const a = group.get('a').value;
    const b = group.get('b').value;
    return of('value').pipe(
      delay(500),
      map((value) => (value === a || value === b ? null : { fields: true }))
    );
  };
}
```

Hope this helps.
[Stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-eguhmg)